# ですら・でも・さえ・だろう（と／が）。 Are there any differences?

Tags: grammar

I am just wondering if anyone can explain the differences between these in terms of nuances.

When I say nuances, can you give examples of whether one is for more polite situations, or whether one is more akin to `regardless of whether X, Y` or `even if X, Y`, or anything like that.

I just can't see myself using anything other than でも if I am stuck believing they are all the same.

Comment: Care to explain your last one "おうとが"? Maybe a simple typo but I can't come up with anything related to your question...

Comment: Fun quiz time! My guess is on something like "どんな人**であろうと**".

Comment: @blutorange なるほど！

Comment: @broccoliforest
http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=%28yo%29uga%2C%28yo%29uto
That's where I got it from.

Comment: So it's intended to be ようが. Since ようが only attaches to verbs, you should use だろうが instead in order to make it consistent with the first three.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Overview

These words have their own meanings, only being alike when translated into English. Those other than `だろう(と/が)` don't convey any politeness or formality by themselves.

The "regardless of whether" sense is shared by: `でも` and `だろうが`.
(but the best choice is `であるかにかかわらず`, I think.)
The "even if" could be shared by: `でも`, `すら` and `さえ`.

#### だろう(と/が) vs. the others

`だろう(と/が)` is the odd one out here, which has little chance to be used in similar situations to the others.
It could be translated into "no matter ..." or "whatever ...", always **connoting subjective emphasis**, usually associated with decision, irritation or even disdain according to the context. It could be formal, but no way polite (neutral ~ offending).

You can duplicate two or more units: `A だろう(と/が) B だろう(と/が)` "no matter A or B"

The grammatical breakdown is `だろう` "will/would be" + `と` "when, whereas" or `が` "though". `だろうと` is literary, while `だろうが` is colloquial.
Note that `だろうと` shares the form with other expression, namely "(say) that ... would ...".

#### でも vs. さえ/すら

`でも` is basically an expression for **enumerating adequate instances** "as like ...", while `さえ` and `すら` are for **convincing by one extreme example** "even ...".
However, a single `でも` could be used as substitution to `さえ`/`すら`, since the only example tends to be used as the most powerful exemplification.

> こんな問題、子供(**でも**/**でさえ**/**ですら**)解ける。 ***Even** a child could solve the problem.*
>
> 難しい問題**でも**考えているのだろうか。 *Is he/she thinking on a difficult problem **or something**?*
> × 難しい問題(でさえ/ですら)

As you can see, `でも` can be duplicated: `A でも B でも` "either A or B", but `さえ`/`すら` not.

`でも` originates from the combination `で` "in (the case of)" + `も` "even, too", thus inevitably shares the form with many other irrelevant expressions, due to `で`'s ambiguity. Especially `でもある` is `も` incorporated in `である` (=だ), and usually has nothing with the expression.

#### さえ vs. すら

As said above, `さえ` and `すら` are used to focus on the most significant example.
There are few reliable sources which could explain the difference between them exhaustively.
In my opinion, their usage is somewhat merging, and highly interchangeable, except for one point observable: `A さえ B` usually means "even [A do B]", while `A すら B` is "[even A] do B".

> 宿題**さえ**なければよかった。 *If **only** there weren't homework.*
> 宿題**すら**なければよかった。*I wish if there weren't **even** homework.*
>
> ○ 愛**さえ**あれば何もいらない。 *I need nothing **as long as** I have love.*
> ? 愛**すら**あれば何もいらない。 *?? I need nothing if I have **even** love.*

Grammatically, when the bare `さえ`/`すら` are used with **transitive** verbs, the words before tend to be interpreted as the objects. Use `でさえ`/`ですら` for the subjects.

> 君**さえ**止められない人間を見たことがない。*I've never seen someone who **even couldn't stop you**.*
> 君**でさえ**止められない人間を見たことがない。*I've never seen someone who **even you couldn't stop**.*